# Are there any halachik issues with reporting a Jewish co-worker to HR?

Tags: halacha, employment

Suppose one has a Jewish co-worker who is not behaving in a manner that's expected at work (ie- confrontational, berating other co-workers, making others feel uneasy)

Granted this isn't something illegal, but could there be any halachik problems with reporting them to HR?

While most times they could potentially get a slap on the wrist, yet there is a chance they could also lose their job-- with the person who reported them being indirectly responsible.

Thoughts?

Comment: Surely speaking to them first would always be preferable, if at all possible (Chafetz Chaim). I'm guessing that a person like that will have trouble stopping, though. What is HR going to do for them that is better? - If you don't speak to them, they are going to lose their job soon.

Comment: Is HR likely to do anything worse to them than what would be halachically reasonable? I don't think so...

Answer (score 3):

I will try to illustrate the problem.

In Gemara BM 83b, the Gemara says that Rabbi Eleazar son of Rabbi Shimeon was a kind of policeman who stops thiefs. Rabbi Yehoshua criticized him. RY said he that he decimated Jewish people. He said this by an allegory, that he was destroying the vine. RE answered that he was destroying brambles. RY said that the owner of the vine needs to destroy brambles (the g-d of Israel), not RA.

> שלח ליה ר' יהושע בן קרחה חומץ בן יין דעד מתי אתה מוסר עמו של אלהינו להריגה שלח ליה קוצים אני מכלה מן הכרם שלח ליה היבא בעל
> הכרם ויכלה את קוציו

A second Gemara more relevant in Gittin 7a

> שלח ליה מר עוקבא לר' אלעזר בני אדם העומדים עלי ובידי למסרם למלכות מהו שרטט וכתב ליה (תהלים לט, ב) אמרתי אשמרה דרכי מחטוא בלשוני אשמרה לפי מחסום בעוד רשע לנגדי אאע"פ שרשע לנגדי אשמרה לפי מחסום שלח ליה קא מצערי לי טובא ולא מצינא דאיקום בהו שלח ליה (תהלים לז, ז) דום לה' והתחולל לו דום לה' והוא יפילם לך חללים חללים השכם והערב עליהן לבהמ"ד והן כלין מאיליהן הדבר יצא מפי ר"א ונתנוהו לגניבא בקולר
>
> Mar Ukva, the Exilarch in Babylonia, sent a letter to Rabbi Elazar, who was in Eretz Yisrael, in which the following was written: With regard to people who stand over and torment me, and I have the power to deliver them into the hands of the government, what is the halakha? May I hand them over to the authorities or not? Rabbi Elazar scored parchment and wrote to him the following verse: “I said: I will take heed to my ways, that I do not sin with my tongue; I will keep a curb upon my mouth, while the wicked is before me” (Psalms 39:2). Rabbi Elazar quoted this verse to allude to the following response: Even though “the wicked is before me,” “I will keep a curb upon my mouth.”  Mar Ukva sent word to him again: They are tormenting me a great deal and I cannot stand them. Rabbi Elazar sent to him in response: “Resign yourself to the Lord, and wait patiently [hitḥolel] for Him; do not fret yourself because of he who prospers in his way, because of the man who brings wicked devices to pass” (Psalms 37:7). This verse indicates: “Resign yourself to the Lord,” i.e., do not do anything, and He will strike them down as many corpses [ḥalalim]. Rise before and stay later than them in your visits to the study hall, and they will disappear on their own. The Gemara relates: The matter emerged from the mouth of Rabbi Elazar, and Geneiva, Mar Ukva’s tormentor, was placed in a neck iron [kolar], as one sentenced by the government.

Rambam in hilchot Chovel Umazik 8.9 ruled:

> אסור [י] למסור האדם ביד עובד כוכבים בין בגופו בין בממונו. ואפילו היה רשע ובעל עבירות ואפילו היה מיצר לו ומצערו. וכל המוסרו ביד עובד כוכבים בין בגופו בין בממונו אין לו חלק לעולם הבא
>
> It's prohibited to denounce a man to an idolatrous, even if he is a miscreant, and makes sins, even if he harasses him and cause him suffering, not only if there are consequences for his body but also for his money. One who makes this has no part in the comming (future) world.

The Rambam is pasted in SA CM 388.9

The Rema added

> הגה: ודוקא בדברים בעלמא אבל אם מסרו מותר למוסרו דהרי יוכל להרגו בדין במקום שיש חשש שיחזור וימסרנו (הרא"ש כלל י"ו סי' א' וב' ותשו' רשב"א סי' קפ"א) או אם אי אפשר להציל עצמו בדרך אחר אבל אם אפשר להציל עצמו בדרך אחר הוי כשנים שמסרו זה את זה וכל מי שהפסיד חבירו יותר חייב לשלם המותר בנזק שלם (מרדכי פ' הנ"ל ותשו' מיימוני הנ"ל) וכל המוסר ישראל ביד עכו"ם בין בגופו בין בממונו אין לו חלק לעולם הבא

He says in the name of the teshuvot haRosh, and Rashba that if he cannot save himself in an other way, he can denounce him. The case there a case of mutually denouncing.

In sayf 12, the SA gives a case un which they can denounce the harasser.

> כל המוסר* הצבור ומצערן מותר למסרו ביד עכו"ם להכותו ולאסרו ולקנסו אבל מפני צער יחיד אסור למסרו:
>
> הגה: (וע"ל סי' תכ"ה ס"א) מי שעוסק בזיופים וכדומה ויש לחוש שיזיק רבים מתרין בו שלא יעשה ואם אינו משגיח יכולין למסרו לומר שאין אחר מתעסק בו אלא זה לבד מי שרוצה לברוח ולא לשלם לעכו"ם מה שחייב ואחר גילה הדבר אין לו דין מוסר שהרי לא הפסידו רק שהוצרך לשלם מה שחייב מ"מ ברעה עשה דהוי כמשיב אבידה לעכו"ם ואם גרם לו היזק חייב לשלם לו מה שגרם לו (מהר"ם מריזבורק):‏
>
> A case of someone *who denounces the congregation and harasses them
> Diverses cases of Jews involved in illegal activities, when his behavior may be dangerous for the congregation. But the congregation needs to advert him before denouncing.

See SMA who linked the two seyfim.

So, there are cases in which you have no choice, you need to denounce him.

- Note. As @user6591 noticed, the Shach corrected the text of the SA, instead of כל המוסר , according to the Shach, the right text is כל המיצר. The text, according to the Shach is a quote of Tur and Rambam. "The one who hurts" instead of "the one who reports to the authorities".

Comment: Siff 12 is a mistake in the print it should say Meitzar Lirabim (like the Rambam and Tur he is quoting) see shach there. And see Igros Moshe Ch'M 1 #8 and O'ch 5 9:11 the only time it is allowed to report the person causing trouble is when he is involved in forgeries and the local rulers will blame and punish all the Jews when the forger is caught. Therefore, reporting him is a war to save all the Jews.

Comment: @user6591 I'll try to look at this further. I'm now very busy. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Given that this co-worker is allegedly confrontational, berating other co-workers, and making others feel uneasy, I would think that OTHER people will also be reporting them to HR. This would make the question moot.

Do you feel the "need" to be the particular person doing the imagined "mitzva" of reporting them?

If you suspect that others won't report the person, then perhaps this is your own perception of your co-worker, which isn't shared by the others.

Alternatively, this person is so toxic, that reporting them to HR, might have severe repercussions, which you might want to consider before reporting them.